# Computing confidence bounds on entropy given an empirical sample from a multinomial distribution?

Tags: statistics

Say we have a multi-state distribution with a finite number of states $i$ where the probability of observing state $i$ in a sample is $p_i$. Suppose we take $N$ samples from this distribution and we get empirical estimates $\hat{p}_i$ for the $p_i$. Now we want to compute an upper confidence limit for the entropy of the distribution, say the 0.95 quantile for entropy. I've read about confidence intervals for binomial distributions but this is multinomial and not only that we want the confidence bound on overall entropy, not the individual confidence bounds on the $p_i$.

Comment: Hello, using a Bayesian approach you can easily get a credibility interval for any function $f(p_1, \ldots, p_d)$. Using the Jeffreys posterior distribution, you can expect that the  $95\%$-credibility interval provides a $\approx 95\%$-confidence interval.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I expect that you mean Bayesian sampling to get a sample based estimate of the confidence interval. If that's what it takes, I'm ok with it but I'm hoping for an analytical answer. E.g. the Wilson confidence interval for binomial proportion.

Comment: The posterior distribution of $(p_1, \ldots, p_d)$ is a Dirichlet distribution. But I don't know what is the function $f$.